# Textchanged event without autopostback in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm working with master page and content page in content page have a Dropdownlist and two textbox when I select any product name from Dropdownlist then retrieve total quantity and price per item from database and assign to tbxTotalQuantity and tbxPricePerItem.I debug the code and notice data retrieve from database but not assign to textboxes..........I want this textchange event occur without autopostback...Hope you can help me...Thanks in advance

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="productNameDDL" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" OnTextChanged="productNameDDL_TextChanged"></asp:DropDownList>





protected void productNameDDL_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(productNameDDL.Text!=string.Empty)
        {
            string name = productNameDDL.Text;

            string queryGetCategory = "select category from smart_shop.inventory where name='" + name + "';";
            category = dbObject.GetStringFromDbs(queryGetCategory, "category");

            string queryGetInfo = "select totalQuantity,pricePerItem from smart_shop.inventory where name='" + name + "';";
            tbxAvailableQuantity.Text = dbObject.GetStringFromDbs(queryGetInfo, "totalQuantity");
            tbxPricePerItem.Text = dbObject.GetStringFromDbs(queryGetInfo, "pricePerItem");
        }

    }
```

Here I'm using custom method for retrieve data from database

Comment: "I want this textchange event occur without autopostback" You aren't using auto-postback. If you were, you'd have `AutoPostBack="true"` as an attribute of your Dropdownlist. Unless you're setting that elsewhere in code-behind? The default value of the property is false, so unless you specifically enable it, auto-postback is disabled.

Comment: When i write AutoPostback="true" trigger is fired but i want this trigger fired without AutoPostback="true"

Comment: Either you use autopostback, or you submit the form to make it postback, which will also fire the trigger. Those are the built-in options. The third option is you turn it into a custom ajax call using javascript and a WCF webservice (or a webmethod).